# Android : Align an ImageView to its parent's bottom

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a very simple RelativeLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listApplications"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <!-- AD SERVER -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ad_server_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ad_banner_image_description"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageView is aligned to the bottom of its parent (RelativeLayout) and I set padding/ margin to 0, but I get a white "border" on the top and bottom of the image (see the red mark):

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: Try setting the `scaletype= fitXY` property in your xml

Comment: May be image having that space.

Comment: I would suggest using LinearLayout as root and ListView with weight="1" and the bottom image wrap_content. As RelativeLayout being the root the bottom image is on top of ListView and it's possible last item cannot be seen.

Comment: I fixed it with  - android:scaleType="fitXY" - Thank you !! Rethinavel Pillai , Could you please copy your comment as answer? I will validate it. Hariharan, thank you for your help !

Comment: Niko : Thank you for your advice, but I cannot use LinearLayout for this layout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to keep the image fit the screen. change your ImageView to this.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ad_server_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"      
        android:contentDescription="@string/ad_banner_image_description"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        />
```

HIH.

Comment: Thank you ~ I fixed it with the scaleTyope option.

Comment: how to do it in linear layout?

Comment: @PalakJain Try ListView with weight="1"

Answer (score 3):

In ImageView you can add this android:adjustViewBounds="true" will work fine!

Answer (score 2):

add attibute `android:layout_above`to the listview, with value `@+id/ad_server_picture`